# Add or update product not working in spurtCommerce

Tags: node.js, angular, opencart, e-commerce, spurt

I unable to add and update product in spurtCommerce 
I am facing 502 Bad Gateway error in console.
its working in version 2.0, but not working in version 2.1.
I don't know what problem is this!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are not sending request properly